# how to replace regular expression based on the match results (e.g. a special function)?

Tags: python, regex

i have a search expression with 1-2 groups.

i need to substitute each result with something that depends on the result value.

e.g. in the following string, replace each matched digit with it's value * 3.

```
s = 'a4cd5cd782cd'
reg = '([1-9])cd'
def f(x): return str(int(x)*3)
```

expected result:

```
'a12cd15cd786cd'
```

how can i substitute with a function?

thanks

Comment: Did you really mean to just multiply the final "2cd" -> "6cd"? Or did you want "782cd" -> "2346cd"? Or should "782cd" be completely skipped because there is more than 1 leading digit before the "cd" part? It's funny how even a simple exercise like this gets complicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a4cd5cd782cd'
>>> reg = r'([1-9])cd'
>>> def f(x): return str(int(x.group(1))*3)+"cd"
...
>>> re.sub(reg, f, s)
'a12cd15cd786cd'
```

Read [the docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the re.sub() method:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

(including an example on calling callback method for each found match).

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

pat = re.compile('[1-9](?=cd)')

def f(x):
    return str(int(x.group())*3) 

s = 'a4cd5cd782cd'
print 'result   :',pat.sub(f,s)
print 'expected : a12cd15cd786cd'
```

or

```
import re

pat = re.compile('[1-9](?=cd)')

def g(x,dic = dict((str(i),str(3*i)) for i in xrange(10))):
    return dic[x.group()]

s = 'a4cd5cd782cd'
print 'result   :',pat.sub(g,s)
print 'expected : a12cd15cd786cd'
```

or with  `dic = dict( (n,str(int(n)*3)) for n in '0123456789')`

or

```
import re

pat = re.compile('[1-9](?=cd)')

def h(x, v = ('0','3','6','9','12','15','18','21','24','27') ):
    return v[int(x.group())]

s = 'a4cd5cd782cd'
print 'result   :',pat.sub(g,s)
print 'expected : a12cd15cd786cd'
```